# how to make StyledItemDelegate draw with default selection style?

Tags: qt, pyqt, pyside

I am using a StyledItemDelegate to render an icon in one of my QTableView's cells.
When a row is selected, I'd like the delegate's background to draw like the default item's background, but am not sure how to tackle it.
I guess the answer lies somewhere between the initStyleOption() method and the delegate's "options", but I can't find comprehensive documentation about those options to figure it out myself.

Help would be greatly appreciated!

Here is some example code that shows how the custom delegate paints a circle, which then ignores the row selection and it's background colour and just stays white:

```
import sys
from PySide.QtGui import *
from PySide.QtCore import *


class MyItemDelegate(QStyledItemDelegate):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyItemDelegate, self).__init__(parent)

    def paint(self, painter, option, index):
        if index.column() == 0:
            rect = option.rect
            rect.setWidth(rect.height())
            painter.drawEllipse(rect)
        else:
            QStyledItemDelegate.paint(self, painter, option, index)


class MyModel (QStandardItemModel):
    def __init__( self, parent=None ):
        super( MyModel, self).__init__( parent )
        self.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(['a', 'b', 'c'])
        self.init_data()

    def init_data(self):
        for row in range(0, 5):
            for col in range(0, 3):
                col_item = QStandardItem( '%s' % (row * col) )
                self.setItem(row, col, col_item)

class MyTableView(QTableView):
    def __init__( self, parent=None ):
        super( MyTableView, self).__init__( parent )
        model = MyModel()
        self.setModel(model)
        self.setItemDelegate(MyItemDelegate())
        self.setSelectionBehavior(QAbstractItemView.SelectRows)

if __name__ == '__main__':   
    app = QApplication( sys.argv )
    model = MyModel()
    view = MyTableView()
    view.show()
    sys.exit( app.exec_() )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should call the base-class paint method before doing your own painting in order to keep the default behaviour:

```
    def paint(self, painter, option, index):
        QStyledItemDelegate.paint(self, painter, option, index)
        if index.column() == 0:
            rect = option.rect
            rect.setWidth(rect.height())
            painter.drawEllipse(rect)
```

Comment: Ha, I could have sworn I tried that before posting. Obviously not. Thanks!