# PyQt5 QTableView selected cell background with Delegate

Tags: pyqt5, qtableview

I have an application which uses a QTableView/QAbstractTableModel combination.  For the view, I've defined a Delegate which displays an image (a QPixmap, loaded from an image file) in one column of the table view.

Basically, the problem is that when a cell in the column with the Delegate is selected, sometimes the background shows and sometimes it doesn't.

Here is what I've discovered by experimentation so far, and I can't make much sense of it:

I have this relatively short test program:

```py
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui
import sys


# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
class TableModel(QtCore.QAbstractTableModel):

    def __init__(self, data = [[]], headers = None, parent = None):
        QtCore.QAbstractTableModel.__init__(self, parent)
        self.__data = data

    def rowCount(self, parent):
        return len(self.__data)

    def columnCount(self, parent):
        return len(self.__data[0])

    def data(self, index, role):
        row = index.row()
        column = index.column()
        if role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
            value = self.__data[row][column]
            return value

    def flags(self, index):
        return QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled|QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEditable|QtCore.Qt.ItemIsSelectable


# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
class Delegate(QtWidgets.QStyledItemDelegate):

    def paint(self, painter, option, index):        

        if (index.column() == 0):
            image = QtGui.QImage('open.png')
            pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap.fromImage(image)

            x = option.rect.center().x() - pixmap.rect().width() / 2
            y = option.rect.center().y() - pixmap.rect().height() / 2
            painter.drawPixmap(x, y, pixmap)


# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyle('fusion')

    tableView = QtWidgets.QTableView()
    tableView.setItemDelegateForColumn(0, Delegate())
    tableView.resize(550, 160)
    tableView.show()

    rowCount = 3
    columnCount = 4
    data = [
        [i for i in range(columnCount)]
        for j in range(rowCount)
    ]

    model = TableModel(data)
    tableView.setModel(model)

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

When I specify `app.setStyle('fusion')` in `__main__`, I get what I would expect:  When a cell in the column with the Delegate is selected, the cell background is blue and the image appears in front of it:

[image: fusion]

However, if I change to `app.setStyle('windows')`, even though in general it uses the same blue background for selected cells, when I move to a cell in the first column, the background disappears:

[image: windows]

(You can't obviously see it, but the same cell is selected as in the first example).

That's just a piece of test code, which I don't completely understand.

In the actual application I'm writing, I am using Qt Designer to create the UI.  Even though I specify `app.setStyle('fusion')`, the table has entirely different styling, with a different appearance to the background of a selected cell:

[image: Qt Designer table]

I can't for the life of me figure out where it is picking up the different style.  It must come from Qt Designer somehow, but I've looked at the .py file Qt Designer creates, and I can't find it.

This style (wherever it comes from) seems to suffer from the same problem as the `windows` style.  In the image above, there is no Delegate in use.  The cell in row 2/column 2 is selected, and the background shows.

But if I add a Delegate to display a QPixmap in column 2, then the background does not show when the cell is selected:

[image: Qt Designer table with Delegate]

(It's selected; take my word for it).

I thought maybe it was the case that once you use a Delegate to display an image, you could no longer get a background in the selected cell.  But you obviously can.  It works in one case, just not the others.

If anyone can shed light on this, I'd appreciate it.  (I realize this is long; thanks for sticking with me).

Comment: Update:  _Don't_ take my word for it.  Actually, the cells shown aren't selected.  In fact, I don't even have the Qt.ItemIsSelectable flag set for the view.  The faint blue highlighting that is shown in the 2nd row/2nd column of the image above (the cell with the 'V' in it) is occurring not because the cell is selected, but because it is the current cell (i.e., the cursor is there).  But I _still_ don't know where that styling is coming from ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been fiddling around with this issue more, and I've learned some things about my original question.  In retrospect, I think it was not as clear as it could have been (or maybe I just understand it all a bit better).

For starters, I never should have referred to cells as being *"selected"*.  In fact, I don't even have the `Qt.ItemIsSelectable` flag set for any of the cells in the view.  What I really have been trying to do is control the background of a cell when it is *active* (for lack of a better word) -- meaning it is the cell where the cursor is currently positioned.

This can be done by overriding `initStyleOption()` in the Delegate.  My original test code is modified as shown below:

```py
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui
import sys


# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
class TableModel(QtCore.QAbstractTableModel):

    def __init__(self, data = [[]], headers = None, parent = None):
        QtCore.QAbstractTableModel.__init__(self, parent)
        self.__data = data

    def rowCount(self, parent):
        return len(self.__data)

    def columnCount(self, parent):
        return len(self.__data[0])

    def data(self, index, role):
        row = index.row()
        column = index.column()
        if role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
            value = self.__data[row][column]
            return value
        if role == QtCore.Qt.BackgroundRole:
            return QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))

    def flags(self, index):
        return QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled|QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEditable


# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
class TableView(QtWidgets.QTableView):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)


# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
class Delegate(QtWidgets.QStyledItemDelegate):

    # <Modification>
    def initStyleOption(self, option, index):
        super().initStyleOption(option, index)
        if (
            index.row() == tableView.currentIndex().row() and
            index.column() == tableView.currentIndex().column()
        ):
            option.backgroundBrush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(232, 244, 252))

    def paint(self, painter, option, index):        
        if (index.column() == 0):

            # <Modification>
            if (
                index.row() == tableView.currentIndex().row() and
                index.column() == tableView.currentIndex().column()
            ):
                self.initStyleOption(option, index)
                painter.setPen(QtCore.Qt.NoPen)
                painter.setBrush(option.backgroundBrush)
                painter.drawRect(option.rect)

            image = QtGui.QImage('open.png')
            pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap.fromImage(image)
            x = option.rect.center().x() - pixmap.rect().width() / 2
            y = option.rect.center().y() - pixmap.rect().height() / 2
            painter.drawPixmap(x, y, pixmap)

        else:
            super().paint(painter, option, index)



# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyle('fusion')

    tableView = TableView()
    tableView.resize(550, 160)
    tableView.setItemDelegate(Delegate())
    tableView.show()

    rowCount = 3
    columnCount = 4
    data = [
        [i for i in range(columnCount)]
        for j in range(rowCount)
    ]

    model = TableModel(data)
    tableView.setModel(model)

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

`initStyleOption()` sets the background brush for a cell when it is active (current).  But as I bemoaned before, this doesn't occur in the first column, which has a Delegate with a custom `paint()` method that displays a pixmap.  So `paint()` must also take responsibility for setting the background for cells in that column when they are active.  It uses the same `backgroundBrush` that `initStyleOption()` set.

The result is very nearly what I'm shooting for.  The only fly in the ointment is that there is still clearly additional styling going on, that affects all the cells in the view except those in column 1 with the custom Delegate.  So they don't look *quite* exactly alike when active:

[image: Column with Delegate]
[image: Column without Delegate]

(It's subtle, but there's a bit of a gradient to the background of the cell in column 2, which is absent in column 1).

I know now that there are style 'factories' that apply a widget-wide style.  Since I'm using Fusion, that is evidently where the extra styling is coming from.

So now my question is -- where is that styling defined, and do I have any control over it?  If I could see it, I could make my custom background style match it.  Better yet, if I could modify it, I could make it match mine.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with my own tool today. I think your issue is the same as [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20322985/how-to-make-styleditemdelegate-draw-with-default-selection-style). In short, you just need to call `super` in `paint` before doing any of your extra work. When I added `super` to my own code, selections worked again as expected in the delegate.

```py
class Delegate(QtWidgets.QStyledItemDelegate):

    def paint(self, painter, option, index):        
        super().paint(painter, option, index)

        if (index.column() == 0):
            image = QtGui.QImage('open.png')
            pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap.fromImage(image)

            x = option.rect.center().x() - pixmap.rect().width() / 2
            y = option.rect.center().y() - pixmap.rect().height() / 2
            painter.drawPixmap(x, y, pixmap)
```

(FWIW I haven't tested the code above. But it should work).